# Migrated 2010 workflow not working in SharePoint 2016

Tags: designer-workflow, error

I have migrated from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2016 testing environment and one of the workflow is not working. The workflow has a condition which is set to if date is 01/01/0001 00:00:00 and this condition was not working.So I removed the condition and added it back and strangely the condition does'nt throw any more error. But, When an item is added to the list the workflow kick starts and shows cancelled immediately with the below error[image]

[image]